# jQuery: disable action of another function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jQuery Toggles plugin: https://github.com/simontabor/jquery-toggles

Here's my code:

```
$(function(){
    $('.toggle').toggles({        
        clicker:'.i-am'
    });
    $('.i-am').click(function(){
        if ($(this).hasClass('active')){
            return false; /* And it doesn't stop the toggling */
        }        
    });
});
```

As you see, I want to disable toggling, when clicking on `.i-am.active`. But `return false;` doesn't do the trick. How can I achieve this?

**Update**. Created jsfiddle to make it clear: http://jsfiddle.net/webstyle/fBpvb/

Comment: Can you post some HTML?

Comment: Can you post a bit more code & details?

Comment: Added jsfiddle example to make it clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/ydBm2/1/

```
$(function(){
    $('.i-am').click(function(e){
        if ($(this).hasClass('active')){
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
            return false; /* This line doesn't work */
        }
        else {
            $('.i-am').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }
    });
    $('.toggle').toggles({
        drag:false,
        click: false, 
        text:{on:'',off:''},
        clicker:'.i-am'
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you. return false; is not needed now, I think.